# Sql query to get value within the substring

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a column with values as,

**CompanyDetails**

```
Id=18, company=3,org=[objectId=18, objectName=Library], parentOrg=null 
Id=10009,company=company=[companyId=3, companyName=CONE],org=[objectId=18, objectName=Library], parentOrg=[objectId=10001, objectName=Cyb 1]
Id=10008, company=3,org=[objectId=10005, objectName=Cyb 5], parentOrg=[objectId=10004, objectName=Cyb 4]
Id=10007, company=3,org=[objectId=10004, objectName=Cyb 4], parentOrg=[objectId=10003, objectName=Cyb 3],
```

The data type of the above column is 'VARCHAR2'.

Now I want to get value of all object Ids in the above column something like this.

```
OrgId
----
18
1004
1005
```

Comment: To clarify, is `org` a column in the row of a table called CompanyDetails, or does each line represent a single value for the field CompanyDetails?

Comment: org is one of the column names in the table CompanyDetails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that object id is the 3rd value, you can use regex_substr to do this.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (column, '\d+', 1, 3)
  FROM table;
```

You can also use regexp_replace, in case it is not the 3rd value always.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (column, '(org=\[objectId=)(\d+)|(.)', '\2')
  FROM table;
```

Comment: Thank you verry much, it helped a lot to me